# Extracting Arabic numerals using OCR and Python

Tags: python, string, replace, ocr

I have an image that I need to extract this number from it ( truth label): `۱٤٤۲٦۷`. I am using EasyOCR:  `results = reader.readtext(image,paragraph = True,text_threshold =0.15,low_text=0.2,add_margin=0.09)`
When I print the text that is output from the OCR, I get :  `رقم :٤٢٦٧ ١٤ (`, so to extract the number I have used: `arabic_num = re.search(r':([\d\s]+)', text, re.UNICODE)` and then the code `print(arabic_num.group(1))` produces `٤٢٦٧ ١٤`. However, when I try to remove the space between `١٤` and `٤٢٦٧` using `arabic_num = arabic_num.group(1).replace(' ', '')` I get ٤٢٦٧١٤. So I have decided to loop over the text to see how it is stored using: `for i in text: print(i)` and the result was:

```
ر
ق
م
 
:
٤
٢
٦
٧
 
١
٤
 
(
```

So it seems that the text is displayed and stored in different ways, so how do I fix this issue and output the text as `۱٤٤۲٦۷` like the truth value in the image ?

Comment: 1) Can you provide the raw bytes of the string, by running `print(arabic_num.encode('utf8'))` ? I think SO may be removing some unicode characters from the question. 2) I think you might have an [invisible RLM character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) in the string.

Comment: @NickODell here is the result b'\xd9\xa4\xd9\xa2\xd9\xa6\xd9\xa7\xd9\xa1\xd9\xa4'

Comment: @NickODell . Note that before printing the raw bytes in my previous comment, arabic_num = arabic_num.group(1).replace(' ', ''), Also the result of arabic_num = re.search(r':([\d\s]+)', text, re.UNICODE)
print(arabic_num.group(1).encode('utf8')) is b'\xd9\xa4\xd9\xa2\xd9\xa6\xd9\xa7 \xd9\xa1\xd9\xa4 '

Answer (score 0):

instead of using:

```
arabic_num.group(1).replace(' ', '')
```

try:

```
numbers = arabic_num.group(1).split(" ")
numbers.reverse()
result = ''.join(numbers)
print(result)
```